# VBA 2003 file search error

Tags: vba, ms-access

So IT recently moved us to office 2010 from office 2003.  With that change, my VBA macro no longer works.  I've searched enough to know its because of the FileSearch Module about halfway down the page that is no longer recongized.  I placed in bold where the issue begins.  Unfortunately I am in the finance field and don't know enough about VBA to fix this issue.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
Function PublishCDCManagementReport()
'                       locate the HTML files generated by the Access report.

' Define Variables to be used by the function:
'Souce & Destination Directories for report pages:
Dim OldPath As String
Dim NewPath As String

'Array to hold Month Names for Subdirectories for path.
'Something like: OldPath "c:\CDCReports\Mgmtrpt\Source"
'                NewPath "c:\CDCReports\Mgmtrpt\WebRpt"
' Report through 0802 So Month = 8
' So final       NewPath = "c:\CDCReports\Mgmtrpt\WebRpt\August"
Dim Months(12) As String
Dim RptNm As String
Dim RptMth As Integer
Dim LineTxt As Variant

' HTML Code to look for to exclude/Add attitional information
Dim SrchString As String
Dim SrchString2 As String
Dim ExcludeTxt As String
Dim Exclude1 As String
Dim Exclude2 As String
Dim StartTime As Date
Dim EndTime As Date
Dim NewFileTxt As Variant
Dim IndexFileTxt As Variant
Dim AddLine As String
Dim CDCName As String
Dim FileSize As Long
Dim NextFile As Integer
Dim GetPrtNo As DAO.Recordset
Dim WebIndex As DAO.Recordset
Dim CRLF As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim GetMth As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim SQL As String
Dim db As Database
Dim IndexFileName As String
Dim Str As String
Dim ZipData As String
Dim Msg As String
Dim frm As String
Dim MyPath As String
Dim ExportReportTo As String


On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
' RUN Access REPORT and output as web pages one page for each page of the report.....
frm = "frmPublishToWebMgmntRpt"
MyPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path

RptNm = "\"
OldPath = MyPath & "\Extract"
NewPath = MyPath & "\Renamed"
IndexFileName = "\rptlist.txt"
ExportReportTo = MyPath & "\Extract\CDCrpt.HTML"
StartTime = Now
DoCmd.Hourglass True
Forms(frm).Label3.Caption = "Running Report 'rptCDCManagementReportbyDistrictOffice' to HTML Files"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptCDCManagementReportbyDistrictOffice", acFormatHTML, ExportReportTo
DoCmd.Hourglass True
Months(1) = "January"
Months(2) = "February"
Months(3) = "March"
Months(4) = "April"
Months(5) = "May"
Months(6) = "June"
Months(7) = "July"
Months(8) = "August"
Months(9) = "September"
Months(10) = "October"
Months(11) = "November"
Months(12) = "December"

GetMth = False 'Indicator to use to only set the report month once.

ExcludeTxt = "<A HREF"
'Carrage return and linefeed characters to format page
CRLF = Chr(13) & Chr(10)
SrchString = "<TD WIDTH=4  ALIGN=LEFT > <BR></TD><TD WIDTH=608  ALIGN=CENTER ><B><I><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:12pt FACE=""Arial"" COLOR=#000000>"
SrchString2 = "<TD WIDTH=4  ALIGN=LEFT > <BR></TD><TD WIDTH=476  ALIGN=CENTER ><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE=""Arial"" COLOR=#000000>CDC Management Report through "
Exclude1 = "<TD WIDTH=4  ALIGN=LEFT > <BR></TD><TD WIDTH=140  ALIGN=LEFT ><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:8pt FACE=""Arial"" COLOR=#000000>Page"
Exclude2 = "<TD WIDTH=4  ALIGN=LEFT > <BR></TD><TD WIDTH=140  ALIGN=LEFT ><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:10pt FACE=""Arial"" COLOR=#000000>"
'SQL Code to get the FIRS number to use in the title. We might change this to PrtId in the future.
SQL = " SELECT cdctblInformation.PIMsNo,cdctblInformation.CDCNo,cdctblInformation.CDCName ,cdctblInformation.[Oversight Office] FROM cdctblInformation WHERE cdctblInformation.CDCNo="
Set db = CurrentDb
'Remove Index rows. This table is used to create the index in the correct sequence.
db.Execute "DELETE * FROM WEBIndex"
'RptNm = "\mangmtrpt"

' Open the table for the index file....
Set WebIndex = db.OpenRecordset("WEBIndex")


**Set fs = Application.FileSearch**
Forms(frm).Label3.Caption = Forms(frm).Label3.Caption & CRLF & "Report Created" & CRLF & "Processing File:"

With fs
    .NewSearch                          'Added 7/2009 to clear Microsoft File Search Cache
    .LookIn = OldPath
    .SearchSubFolders = True
    .FileName = "*.HTML"
    If .Execute() > 0 Then              'Finds files in folder stored in "OldPath
    'MsgBox "There were " & .FoundFiles.Count & " file(s) found."

         x = 0
         NextFile = True
        For I = 1 To .Execute()         ' Replaced hard coded value of 288 with search count 11/2010

            Open .FoundFiles(I) For Input As #1
           If NextFile Then
            CDCName = ""
            NewFileTxt = ""
            End If
            cnt = 0


            Do While Not EOF(1)
             Input #1, LineTxt
             cnt = cnt + 1


            If InStr(LineTxt, SrchString) <> 0 Then
                   CDCName = Right(LineTxt, 6)
                 End If
            If InStr(LineTxt, ExcludeTxt) <> 0 Or InStr(LineTxt, "</HTML>") <> 0 Then
            ' Do nothing we don't want this html
            Else
            'Append Txt
             If Not NextFile Then ' This is a continuation file (i.e. Report was more than 1 page)
               If cnt <= 6 Then 'We want to remove the repeated Header so ignore this data
               Else
                NewFileTxt = NewFileTxt & LineTxt & CRLF
               End If
             Else
               If InStr(LineTxt, Exclude1) <> 0 Then
               Else
                If InStr(LineTxt, Exclude2) <> 0 Then
                         Input #1, LineTxt ' We want to skip this line
                Else
                If GetMth = False Then ' Do determine the Directory to place this in we need to report through date
                   If InStr(LineTxt, SrchString2) <> 0 Then
                     Str = Right(LineTxt, Len(LineTxt) - 147)
                     RptMth = CInt(Left(Str, InStr(Str, "/") - 1))
                     NewPath = NewPath & "\" & Months(RptMth)
                     GetMth = True
                     IndexFileName = NewPath & IndexFileName
                     Open IndexFileName For Output As #3
                   End If
                   NewFileTxt = NewFileTxt & LineTxt & CRLF
                Else
                   NewFileTxt = NewFileTxt & LineTxt & CRLF
                End If
              End If
            End If
          End If
         End If
         Loop
         Close #1
         If (I = .FoundFiles.Count) Then
           FileSize = FileLen(.FoundFiles(I))
          Else
           FileSize = FileLen(.FoundFiles(I + 1))
         End If
          If FileSize > 10000 Then
            If CDCName <> "" Then
                   Set GetPrtNo = db.OpenRecordset(SQL + "'" + CDCName + "';")
                If Not GetPrtNo.EOF Then
                  GetPrtNo.MoveFirst
               '  NewFile = NewPath & RptNm & CDCName & ".html"
                  NewFile = NewPath & RptNm & UCase(GetPrtNo("PIMsNo")) & ".htm"
                  WebIndex.AddNew
                  WebIndex("FIRSNo") = UCase(GetPrtNo("PIMsNo"))
                  WebIndex("OversightOffice") = GetPrtNo("Oversight Office")
                  WebIndex("CDCNo") = GetPrtNo("CDCNo")
                  WebIndex("CDCName") = GetPrtNo("CDCName")
                  WebIndex.Update

                End If





              Open NewFile For Output As #2
               NewFileTxt = NewFileTxt & "<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>"
               NewFileTxt = NewFileTxt & "<TR height=14>"
               NewFileTxt = NewFileTxt & "<TD align=middle width=626><FONT face=""Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif""><B>&lt;&lt; <FONT size=-1>"
               NewFileTxt = NewFileTxt & "<a href=""javascript:history.back()"" title=""Link to go back to the previous page"">BACK</a>&gt;&gt;</FONT></B></FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>"
               NewFileTxt = NewFileTxt & "</BODY> </HTML>" & CRLF
               Print #2, NewFileTxt
              Close #2
              Forms(frm).Label3.Caption = "Processing File:" & x
             DoCmd.RepaintObject acForm, frm


              x = x + 1
            NextFile = True
             End If
            Else
            NextFile = False
            x = x + 1
            End If



        Next I
        WebIndex.Index = "PrimaryKey"

        WebIndex.MoveFirst
        Do While Not WebIndex.EOF

         IndexFileTxt = WebIndex("FIRSNo") & "  [" & WebIndex("OversightOffice") & "]  " & WebIndex("CDCNo") & " " & WebIndex("CDCName") '& CRLF
                  Print #3, IndexFileTxt
        WebIndex.MoveNext

       Loop
              WebIndex.Close
        Close #3
        ChDir NewPath
        ZipData = "pkzip -a -p " & Format(RptMth, "00") & " *.*"
        z = Shell(ZipData, 0)
        EndTime = Now
        Msg = "Report produced " & .FoundFiles.Count & "Files Of which " & x & " Where PROCESSED " & CRLF
        Msg = Msg & "To " & CurDir & CRLF
        Msg = Msg & "The Processing Took: " & CRLF & "Start: " & StartTime & CRLF & "End: " & EndTime & CRLF
        x = Int(DateDiff("s", StartTime, EndTime) / 60)
        Msg = Msg & "Minutes: " & x & ":" & DateDiff("s", StartTime, EndTime) - (x * 60) & CRLF
        Msg = Msg & "Zip File: " & Format(RptMth, "00") & ".Zip Created"
         Forms(frm).Label3.Caption = Msg
          Forms(frm).Label9.Caption = "/opt/netscape/suitespot/docs/mgmtrpt/CDC/" & Format(RptMth, "00") & "_" & Months(RptMth)
         Forms(frm).Command1.Enabled = True
         Forms(frm).Command6.Visible = True
         Forms(frm).Command8.Enabled = True
    Else
        MsgBox "There were no files found."
    End If
End With



'new code
       Else: End If

    Next

Else

MsgBox "No Files Found at " & FILE_PATH

End If

Set FSO = Nothing
Set FSO_FOLDER = Nothing
'new code


DoCmd.Hourglass False
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
Select Case Err
Case 2501
If MsgBox("You have cancelled the creation of the WEB Pages. Are you Sure?", vbYesNo, "Cancelled") = vbYes Then
Else
Resume
End If
Case Else
MsgBox "error: " & Err & " " & Error
End Select



End Function
```

Comment: please check the DLL libarary refrence. [snapshot](http://www.google.com/imgres?sa=X&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&biw=1080&bih=1091&tbm=isch&tbnid=Rv7uKsL4iiHhDM:&imgrefurl=http://www.databison.com/excel-treemap/excel-treemap-add-in-documentation/&docid=tx1nFPhYNl0fDM&imgurl=http://www.databison.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/reference-vba-ide.png&w=532&h=263&ei=m6QwUoSpIOTB2QXf6YDoCg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:6,s:0,i:99&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=153&tbnw=310&start=0&ndsp=20&tx=89&ty=84)

Comment: FileSearch was removed in Excel 2007. You can use `Dir()` or the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to replace it. Plenty of examples via Google "vba FileSearch replacement"

Comment: Unforunately I don't know much about VBA.  Is it a direct word for word replacement, or do I need ot change other parts of the code?

Comment: This was written by an employee in 2002 that is no longer working here.  Needless to say it is old code.  I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: That's exactly what I had intended.  Sorry that I wasted your time forcing you to read this and respond.  Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Sub which can do the work of FileSearch (at least as you use it..)

```
'Fill a Collection with all files matching "Pattern"
'  Optionally search subfolders
Sub GetFiles(StartFolder As String, Pattern As String, _
             DoSubfolders As Boolean, ByRef colFiles As Collection)

    Dim f As String, sf As String, subF As New Collection, s

    If Right(StartFolder, 1) <> "\" Then StartFolder = StartFolder & "\"

    f = Dir(StartFolder & Pattern)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        colFiles.Add StartFolder & f
        f = Dir()
    Loop

    sf = Dir(StartFolder, vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(sf) > 0
        If sf <> "." And sf <> ".." Then
            If (GetAttr(StartFolder & sf) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                    subF.Add StartFolder & sf
            End If
        End If
        sf = Dir()
    Loop

    For Each s In subF
        GetFiles CStr(s), Pattern, DoSubfolders,  colFiles 'EDIT!
    Next s

End Sub
```

Here's how it might fit into your current code:

```
Dim colFiles As New Collection, f As Variant
Dim numFiles as Long   
'...
'...
'...
Set WebIndex = Db.OpenRecordset("WEBIndex")

Forms(frm).Label3.Caption = Forms(frm).Label3.Caption & _
        CRLF & "Report Created" & CRLF & "Processing File:"

GetFiles OldPath, "*.HTML", True, colFiles
numFiles = colFiles.Count

If numFiles > 0 Then

    MsgBox "There were " & numFiles & " file(s) found."

    For i = 1 to numFiles

        f = colFiles(i)
        Open f For Input As #1  'EDIT!
        '...
        '... do stuff
        '...
        Close #1
        '...
        '...
        '...

    Next i        
End If
```

Comment: Tim, I thank you for your time you've spent helping me with this issue. I receive an error at Open.Foundfiles(I) For Input As #1.

Comment: OK. So I take it I run my #2 and #3 and I before I end #3 I use Next f? I only ask because I have multiple instances of FoundFiles in the rest of the macro.  I'm trying to determine how to use your advice to change my other coding.  I am such a newb.

Comment: Edited my suggested code to more closely match your existing method. Sorry - I don't have time to run through the whole thing...

Comment: I appreciate your assistance Tim.  Unfortunately I just don't know enough about this type of thing.  Regardless, you are very kind.